# DhtmlScheduler timeline coloring the weekends

Tags: javascript, css, dhtmlx-scheduler

If I am using the timeline view, how do I make weekends a different color from the rest of the weekdays? For example, how to change the weekend background color to say light yellow.
I have tried using this but if that month does not contain a event then the color does not change.

```
 scheduler.templates.timeline_cell_class = function(evs, x, y) {
                if (x.getDay() == 6 || x.getDay() == 0) {
                    return getWeekendClass();
                }
                };

var getWeekendClass = function() {
        return "weekend_cell";
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still need an answer, the only thing you need to do is:

```
scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({
    days: [0, 6],   // Sunday and Saturday
    zones: "fullday",
    css: "scheduler_weekends"
});
```

where scheduler_weekends is something like:

```
.scheduler_weekends {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

This will show weekends in yellow in all views except month view.
For it to show in month view, you have to add to your CSS:

```
.dhx_scheduler_month .dhx_marked_timespan { display: block; }
```